# Error Installing Pandas using pip, Windows 7 64bit Python 3.2

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to install the pandas library on Python 3.2 on Windows 7 64bit.

The pip log is here.
http://pastebin.com/Vuitwaz9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend trying to build pandas (or any Python library containing C extensions) on 64-bit Windows *unless* you are using the [Enthought Python Distribution](http://enthought.com) (which comes bundled with a viable build environment) or you are in the mood for a [yak shaving expedition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving) (you would need to install the VS2008 SDK and do some finagling of Python's distutils config). You can find one-click binary installers for pandas 64-bit Python 3.2 on the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas).

Comment: I tried using the binaries however when I run the nosetests I get alot of failures.  http://pastebin.com/8pyffPyN

Comment: You need scipy to use those functions in pandas 0.7.3 (I've trimmed the scipy dependency for the next pandas release). You can find a binary installers for the latest SciPy here (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). Note that installers from that page may require that you install his NumPy MKL build (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: That worked.  I originally didn't install it because it was listed as an optional dependency.  Thanks for the help.